# Find table elements to fill forms selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, html-table, locate

My code so far is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://moodle.tau.ac.il/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('page-content')//form[@id='login']// \
                         input[@type='submit']").click()
```

Now I'm trying to fill up the login form and I succeeded to find the division
that follows id= content, easy to see in the image:

[image: Image of the page]

The following code line I used:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('content'))
```

but it doesn't recognize anything in it and I cant get any further, what should I do to locate the input element?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't recognize anything because *it is in an iframe*. Therefore, you first have to switch to the iframe and then search the login form.

Switch to the iframe:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('credentials')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Or:

```
driver.switch_to.frame('credentials')
```